# Skip duplicates uploads with Google photos?

Tags: google-photos

Yesterday I joined the Google Photos new service.

I selected  huge libraries ( images and videos) and dragged them to the browser for upload.

It is already taking 3 days now (uploading)

[image]

**Question:**

what if my computer goes shutdown for some reason ?

I know that I will have to do it again since it doesnt skip existing files.

Is there any solution to this scenario where browser is closed / computer gets shutdown /reset or something ?

Comment: The web upload is okay for a few files, but if you have hundreds or thousands you really should download and install the [Desktop Uploader](https://photos.google.com/apps).

Comment: Mind you that the Desktop Uploader will most likely not detect date and time of videos. It will mess up your timeline. Alle videos will appear to be taken today. Just drag you entire archive using the browser to Google Photo. It works fine for 100GB+. That way the date taken of video will be maintained. Date taken of pictures are maintained by the Desktop Uploader just fine though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing when I had to shut down my computer yesterday during a 3000+ photo transfer. It seems to skip duplicates now that I upload them again. I tried just uploading a folder of ~20 photos that were already on my google photos and it chugs through them as usual (uploads them) but there's just one copy in my library so it seems to have some way of skipping duplicates.

Comment: Did it upload the whole file and then saw it is a dup , or did it send a CRC or something before  - to check if there's already a file on the server ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir It definitely detects duplicates much faster than uploading new photos.  I'm sure it sends some hash of the photo or something first before uploading it.